# Python, why def() is not working in this case?

Tags: python, tkinter

This code runs OK and displays resized_image:

---

```
# replicates "def place_image()" steps,
# image correctly displayed on canvas:
img = resized_image
widget  = canvas
x = 0
y = 0
anch = NW
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) #Convert To photoimage
widget.create_image(x, y, anchor = anch, image=photo)
```

---

This one just displays a black canvas:

```
# this does nothing, just a black canvas
def place_image(widget, x, y, anch, img):
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) #Convert To photoimage
    widget.create_image(x, y, anchor = anch, image=photo)

place_image(canvas, 0, 0, NW, resized_image)
```

---

What is the difference?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. There must be a difference in the way you're using the code in each case.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because it has stored the variable containing the image in a local variable which is removed immediately afterwards, so my advice is to store the variable globally.

so:

```
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) #Convert To photoimage
def place_image(widget, x, y, anch):
    widget.create_image(x, y, anchor = anch, image=photo)

place_image(canvas, 0, 0, NW)
```

Comment: I get it, but I need to move
 def place_image(widget, x, y, anch):
etc.
to another module, being able to call it from the main python file with:
place_image(canvas, 0, 0, NW, resized_image)

How can I do it?

Comment: @Rec if you have to use a few images I suggest you import them too, else i suggest you to store them in a data structure (depending on your code) and then import it.